# Python CoreProperties python-docx

Tags: python-3.x, docx

I need to know the core properties of a docx as author, language, created (date), identifier, last_printed, modified (date), version, title, subject. I wrote this code:

```
import docx
import os

os.chdir('C:\\abc\\Documents')
doc = docx.Document('ATD.docx')

docx.opc.coreprops.CoreProperties.author(doc)
```

I am getting this error:

> TypeError: 'property' object is not callable

How can I get the information I need from a python code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm using python-docx `0.8.10`, not sure if [core properties](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dev/analysis/features/coreprops.html) were supported back then but now things should be pretty simple:

```
print(doc.core_properties.author)
>> 'name of the author'
```

in order to list all available properties do:

```
print(doc.core_properties.__dir__())
```

note that you can also set new value for properties like `identifier`, `author`, etc.

```
doc.core_properties.author = '#stayathome!' # aren't we all enjoying covid-19
print(doc.core_properties.author)
>> '#stayathome!'
```

Hope this helps,

Best