# python-docx: How to get the document properties into an object

Tags: python, python-docx, python-pptx

I'm using python-docx and I can list the properties with `doc.core_properties.__dir__()` [as in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52120217/python-coreproperties-python-docx).
But assigning prs.core_properties to a python variable doesn't give a usable object.

How do I get the document properties into a python object?

Here is what I tried:

```py
from pptx import Presentation
import os

pptFile = "myfile.pptx"
prs = Presentation(os.path.realpath(pptFile))
prsProps = prs.core_properties
print(prs.core_properties.__dir__())
print(prs.core_properties.modified)
prsProps
```

yields

```
['_partname', '_content_type', '_package', '_blob', '_element', '_rels', '__module__', '__doc__', 'default', 'author', 'category', 'comments', 'content_status', 'created', 'identifier', 'keywords', 'language', 'last_modified_by', 'last_printed', 'modified', 'revision', 'subject', 'title', 'version', '_new', '__init__', 'load', 'blob', 'part', 'content_type', 'drop_rel', 'load_rels_from_xml', 'package', 'partname', 'rels', '_blob_from_file', '_rel_ref_count', 'part_related_by', 'relate_to', 'related_part', 'target_ref', '__dict__', '__weakref__', '__new__', '__repr__', '__hash__', '__str__', '__getattribute__', '__setattr__', '__delattr__', '__lt__', '__le__', '__eq__', '__ne__', '__gt__', '__ge__', '__reduce_ex__', '__reduce__', '__getstate__', '__subclasshook__', '__init_subclass__', '__format__', '__sizeof__', '__dir__', '__class__']
2019-11-15 12:30:37
<pptx.parts.coreprops.CorePropertiesPart at 0x1d9a3fa6fd0>
```

I expected an object in `prsProps`.

Comment: Please, post [mre]. _doesn't give a usable object_ is unclear - do you get error or what? What is considered "usable object"?

Comment: @buran - I added an example

Comment: So, you are getting `pptx.parts.coreprops.CorePropertiesPart` object (remember - everything is an object in python). Here is the relevant [source code](https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/blob/71d1ca0b2b3b9178d64cdab565e8503a25a54e0b/pptx/parts/coreprops.py#L13)

Comment: By the way, in your question you speak of `python-docx`, while the sample code is about `python-pptx`

Comment: Yes, as I read the meta data is identical. More discussions go to docx. That's why I used this headline.

Answer (score 0):

To get docx core-properties you simply access it on the document object:

```py
>>> core_properties = document.core_properties
>>> core_properties
<docx.opc.coreprops.CoreProperties at 0x...>
```

`CoreProperties` is an object with 14 read/write properties, documented here:

https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#coreproperties-objects